# Cómo puedo rediseñar un elemento select del framework materializecss?

Tags: jquery, html5, web, select, materialize

Tengo un problema. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y estoy usando el framework Materializecss. Uso varios elementos  (unos multiples y otros simples). El caso es que los elementos  simples deben tener un diseño un tanto particular. No debe quedar el dipico diseño dropdown, sino que cuando se cargue la pagina debe salirme un cuadro y dentro de ese cuadro deben salirme las dos opciones pero en forma "inline-block", es decir no una debajo de otro, sino una al lado de la otra. y que al hacer click una de las opciones esta tome un color de fondo diferente y que se mantenga mientras esa opcion este seleccionada. El diseño debe quedar más o menos asi:

[image: Asi deberia quedarme el diseño final del select]

el codigo del select es:

```
<select> <option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option</select>
```

Es primera vez que trabajo con este framework, estuve buscando alguna documentacion al respecto y por lo que pude ver los elementos  les dan cierto manejo con Jquery. No se como optener el diseño que quiero.

Alguien me puede ayudar? Alguien que sepa mucho de Materializecss y de como cambiar la el nombre de la clase de un elemento html con JQuery.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas

Basicamente es cambiar las classes y ponerle los estilos que quieras, la libreria hace una lista `ul` con items `li` que podemos manipular bien sea con `css` o `js`

Saludos espero te ayude

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
```

```css
.dropdown-content li {
  float: left;
  width: 50% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  clear:none !important;
}
.dropdown-content,.input-field {
  width:100px !important;
}
.input-field {
  margin: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
    <select>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Te paso el codepen para que lo revises mejor

[Codepen Materialize select](https://codepen.io/lusaxweb/pen/MOqwWo)

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu aporte. Es de gran ayuda, sin embargo digamos que me resuelve una primera parte del problema. Lo que yo deseo es que Cuando abra el html de mi formulario o recargue esa pagina, ese campo select se muestre ya abierto y con las dos opciones asi, una al lado de la otra. La idea es que se quede asi como un bloque y con las dos opciones una al lado de la otra.

Comment: O por lo menos que al darle click al select se abran las dos opciones y se mantengan asi hasta que le de guardar a mi formulario o que recargue la pagina. Yo probe borrar las clases dropdown-content y select-dropdowm por medio del inspector de codigo y luego le agregue unos estilos css y cool me quedo como deseaba pero obviamente que al recargar la pagina eso se pierde y vuelven a aparecer las clases